# create & read from tempfile

Tags: python

Is there anyway I could write to tempfile and include it in a command, and then close/remove it? I would like to execute the command, eg: some_command /tmp/some-temp-file.

```
import tempfile
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
temp.write('Some data')
command=(some_command temp.name)
temp.close()
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you need a temporary file with a name you have to use the `NamedTemporaryFile` function. Then you can use `temp.name`. Read 
http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html for details.

Comment: @balki or you can pass `bufsize=0` to make it unbuffered.

Answer (score 93):

Complete example.

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write('Some data')
    if should_call_some_python_function_that_will_read_the_file():
       temp.seek(0)
       some_python_function(temp)
    elif should_call_external_command():
       temp.flush()
       subprocess.call(["wc", temp.name])
```

**Update**: As mentioned in the comments, this may not work in windows. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344603) solution for windows

**Update 2**: Python3 requires that the string to be written is represented as bytes, not str, so do instead

```
temp.write(bytes('Some data', encoding = 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Just want to add that if the command is replaced by some Python code (like a function call) make sure you do temp.seek(0) so if that function tries to read the content it won't be empty handed.

Comment: +1 for the use of _with_. Is there a reason why the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) doesn't use _with_?

Comment: Make sure you consider this from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile): "Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, *varies across platforms* (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later)." Note that using the `with` statement keeps the tempfile open when you're calling `command`, and as such your code's portability is impacted.

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
import tempfile
import commands
import os

commandname = "cat"

f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
f.write("oh hello there")
f.close() # file is not immediately deleted because we
          # used delete=False

res = commands.getoutput("%s %s" % (commandname,f.name))
print res
os.unlink(f.name)
```

It just prints the content of the temp file, but that should give you the right idea. Note that the file is closed (`f.close()`) before the external process gets to see it. That's important -- it ensures that all your write ops are properly flushed (and, in Windows, that you're not locking the file). `NamedTemporaryFile` instances are usually deleted as soon as they are closed; hence the `delete=False` bit.

If you want more control over the process, you could try `subprocess.Popen`, but it sounds like `commands.getoutput` may be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: This answer (especially `delete=False` & `close()`) is key information for the Windows case. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and its member `name` instead. A regular `TemporaryFile` isn't even guaranteed to have a name, due to the way [Unix filesystems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219896/how-do-the-unix-commands-mv-and-rm-work-with-open-files/5219960#5219960) work.