# Python S3 download zip file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, zip

I have zip files uploaded to S3. I'd like to download them for processing. I don't need to permanently store them, but I need to temporarily process them. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you want to simply download it without extracting any file, it's also possible to use the `download_file` method as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474927/11764049

Answer (score 31):

Because **working software > comprehensive documentation**:

### Boto2

```
import zipfile
import boto
import io

# Connect to s3
# This will need your s3 credentials to be set up 
# with `aws configure` using the aws CLI.
#
# See: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
conn = boto.s3.connect_s3()

# get hold of the bucket
bucket = conn.get_bucket("my_bucket_name")

# Get hold of a given file
key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
key.key = "my_s3_object_key"

# Create an in-memory bytes IO buffer
with io.BytesIO() as b:

    # Read the file into it
    key.get_file(b)

    # Reset the file pointer to the beginning
    b.seek(0)

    # Read the file as a zipfile and process the members
    with zipfile.ZipFile(b, mode='r') as zipf:
        for subfile in zipf.namelist():
            do_stuff_with_subfile()
```

### Boto3

```
import zipfile
import boto3
import io

# this is just to demo. real use should use the config 
# environment variables or config file.
#
# See: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="ACCESSKEY", 
    aws_secret_access_key="SECRETKEY"
)

s3 = session.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket('stackoverflow-brice-test')
obj = bucket.Object('smsspamcollection.zip')

with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:

    # rewind the file
    tf.seek(0)

    # Read the file as a zipfile and process the members
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
        for subfile in zipf.namelist():
            print(subfile)
```

Tested on MacOSX with Python3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know any way to do this on boto3?

Comment: @brice getting 'no such file or directory' when i try to actually `with open(subfile, 'r') as file:`

Comment: I do not believe this method will work with very large (~>2GB) zip files.  You will get a "Python int too large to convert to C long" when you try to read the zip file with the line "with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["body].read()) as tf:"    I have been unable to find a reliable way to open a S3 zip file that is larger than 2GB.

Comment: @partydog that is because it is just printing the names of the files within the zip file.

Comment: How can we read this in pandas? I tried adding the subfile as a parameter but it throws the following error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Found the answer to my own question - If it helps anyone
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
        for line in zipf.read("xyz.csv").split(b"\n"):
            print(line)

Answer (score 4):

Pandas provides a shortcut for this, which removes most of the code from the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28196540/9035107), and allows you to be agnostic about whether your file path is on s3, gcp, or your local machine.

```
import pandas as pd  

obj = pd.io.parsers.get_filepath_or_buffer(file_path)[0]
with io.BytesIO(obj.read()) as byte_stream:
    # Use your byte stream, to, for example, print file names...
    with zipfile.ZipFile(byte_stream, mode='r') as zipf:
        for subfile in zipf.namelist():
            print(subfile)
```

Answer (score 3):

If speed is a concern, a good approach would be to choose an EC2 instance fairly close to your S3 bucket (in the same region) and use that instance to unzip/process your zipped files.

This will allow for a latency reduction and allow you to process them fairly efficiently. You can remove each extracted file after finishing your work.

Note: This will only work if you are fine using EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have heard `boto` which is `Python interface to Amazon Web Services`

You can get `key` from `s3` to `file`.

```
import boto
import zipfile.ZipFile as ZipFile

s3 = boto.connect_s3() # connect
bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name) # get bucket
key = bucket.get_key(key_name) # get key (the file in s3)
key.get_file(local_name) # set this to temporal file

with ZipFile(local_name, 'r') as myzip:
    # do something with myzip

os.unlink(local_name) # delete it
```

You can also use `tempfile`. For more detail, see [create & read from tempfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344287/create-read-from-tempfile)

Answer (score 1):

## Reading certain file from a zip file from S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import os
import zipfile
import io
import json


'''
When you configure awscli, you\'ll set up a credentials file located at 
~/.aws/credentials. By default, this file will be used by Boto3 to authenticate.
'''
os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = "<profile_name>"
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "<region_name>"

# Let's use Amazon S3
s3_name = "<bucket_name>"
zip_file_name = "<zip_file_name>"
file_to_open = "<file_to_open>"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(s3_name, zip_file_name )

with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:
    # rewind the file
    tf.seek(0)
    # Read the file as a zipfile and process the members
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
        file_contents= zipf.read(file_to_open).decode("utf-8")
        print(file_contents)
```

reference from @brice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @brice answer

---

Here is the code if you want to read any data inside the file line by line

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
    for line in zipf.read("xyz.csv").split(b"\n"):
        print(line)
        break # to break off after the first line
```

Hope this helps!