# Read npy file directly from S3 StreamingBody

Tags: python, json, numpy, amazon-s3

I have many .npy (numpy) and .json files saved in s3, I need to download and load these files.

For the json files I am downloading the files and loading into dictionary using the following code:

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
response = obj.get()
body = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(body)
```

That way I avoid writing the .json file to disk and reading it.

Now I want to do the same for the .npy files, what would be the equivalent?

Currently I am downloading the file, saving to temp file on disk and loading with `np.load` but would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/28196540/3509999:

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as f:
    # rewind the file
    f.seek(0)
    arr = np.load(f)
```

Comment: This gives the error: ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False

Answer (score 0):

The correct answear should be:

```
numpy_image = np.fromstring(s3_object.get()['Body'].read(), np.uint8)
```

and if you would like to get the image from it you can use cv2 like in the example below:

```
image = cv2.imdecode(numpy_image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```