# How do I read a zipped CSV from S3 using python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to read a zipped CSV file which is stored on S3.
I am able to read CSV using boto3 but not able to read zipped CSV.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find a solution here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376816/python-s3-download-zip-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python S3 download zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376816/python-s3-download-zip-file)

Comment: What do you actually want to _do_ with the file? For example, are you wanting to query data stored in the file? If so, Amazon S3 Select might be useful. How big is the file (how many rows)? Is it just one file, or many files? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.