# Twisted I/O archive files

Tags: python, json, twisted, archive

I'm having troubles writing asynchronous I/O program. What I'm trying to achieve is: dump json data into a temporary file so I can then use subprocess to create an archive of that file (with json data). However I figured out that I'm trying to tar an empty file from `tempfile.NamedTemporatyFile`.

```
    serialized_data = {'a': 1}

    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='.', prefix='serialized_', suffix='.json')
    temp_file.write(json.dumps(serialized_data))

    arch_name = temp_file.name + '.tar.gz'
    tar_cmd_args = ['tar', '-czf', arch_name, temp_file.name]
    subprocess.call(tar_cmd_args)
    #d = threads.deferToThread(subprocess.call, tar_cmd_args)
```

I'm trying to avoid I/O as much as possible since I don't want to block callback chain and I have to be sure those operations are thread safe. 
Or is another way of solution to my problem? I really want to avoid `json.dump(serialized, file_name)`

[edit]

While `temp_file.close()` caused:
`tar: /home/bartosz/Documents/serialized_mnaFP_.json: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

The solution was no to close the file, but to flush.
`temp_file.flush()`

[create & read from tempfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344287/create-read-from-tempfile)

Answer (score 1):

Close the file after you write to it and before launching the secondary thread.

Comment: Now I'm getting:
        `tar: Removing leading / from member names`
        `tar: /home/bartosz/Documents/serialized_mnaFP_.json: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`
        `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`
and there is no file in the archive now, not even an empty one as previous