# Check if an open file has been deleted after open in python

Tags: python, filesystems

Is it possible to check if a file has been deleted or recreated in python?

For example, if you did a `open("file")` in the script, and then while that file is still open, you do `rm file; touch file;`, then the script will still hold a reference to the old file even though it's already been deleted.

Comment: maybe os.path.exists work in this case?

Comment: the problem with os.path.exists is that another file with the same path name may exist, even though the old file was already deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use [the `os.stat()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) to check the file length. If the length is zero (or the function returns the error "File not found"), then someone deleted the file.

Alternatively, you can open+write+close the file each time you need to write something into it. The drawback is that opening a file is a pretty slow operation, so this is out of the question if you need to write a lot of data.

Why? Because the new file isn't the file that you're holding open. In a nutshell, Unix filesystems have two levels. One is the directory entry (i.e. the file name, file size, modification time, pointer to the data) and the second level is the file data.

When you open a file, Unix uses the name to find the file data. After that, it operates only on the second level - changes to the directory entry have no effect on any open "file handles". Which is exactly why you can delete the directory entry: Your program isn't using it.

When you use `os.stat()`, you don't look at the file data but at the directory entry again.

On the positive side, this allows you to create files which no one can see but your program: Open the file, delete it and then use it. Since there is no directory entry for the file, no other program can access the data.

On the negative side, you can't easily solve problems like the one you have.

Comment: On Linux you could look into `proc/<pid>/fd/...` and access the data even if the file was deleted. That sometimes comes in handy if you want to make a copy of a video you are downloading from youtube ;-)

Comment: @hochl: Interesting. Note: To read the contents of the `fd` directory of a process, you need to be that user or root (permissions are `dr-x------`), so it's still secure.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I just did a quick test, and I was able to do what I wanted with fstat (since stat still takes a filename) and looking at st_nlink (the number of hardlinks). I don't think the file length changes when it gets deleted.

Comment: Checking for the file length is very unreliable -- what if someone creates a file with the same name **and length**? See my answer for a more reliable approach.

Comment: I agree, your answer catches more corner cases.

Comment: @user1502906: You should not use the term "file" in your case; it's very confusing. Be specific. The file data of the open file doesn't change but `stat()` should check the directory entry (i.e. the new file) and when you touch the new file, the new file data should have the length 0.

Answer (score 24):

You should `fstat` the file descriptor for the opened file.

```
>>> import os
>>> f = open("testdv.py")
>>> os.fstat(f.fileno())
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=1508053, st_dev=65027L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=1107, st_atime=1349180541, st_mtime=1349180540, st_ctime=1349180540)
>>> os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_nlink
1
```

Ok, this file has one link, so one name in the filesystem. Now remove it:

```
>>> os.unlink("testdv.py")
>>> os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_nlink
0
```

No more links, so we have an "anonymous file" that's only [kept alive as long as we have it open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5219960/166749). Creating a new file with the same name has no effect on the old file:

```
>>> g = open("testdv.py", "w")
>>> os.fstat(g.fileno()).st_nlink
1
>>> os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_nlink
0
```

Of course, `st_nlink` can sometimes be `>1` initially, so checking that for zero is not entirely reliable (though in a controlled setting, it might be good enough). Instead, you can verify whether the file at the path you initially opened is the same one that you have a file descriptor for by comparing `stat` results:

```
>>> os.stat("testdv.py") == os.fstat(f.fileno())
False
>>> os.stat("testdv.py") == os.fstat(g.fileno())
True
```

(And if you want this to be 100% correct, then you should compare only the `st_dev` and `st_ino` fields on `stat` results, since the other fields and `st_atime` in particular might change in between the calls.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes -- you can use the `inotify` facility to check for file changes and more. There also is a Python [binding](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) for it. Using inotify you can watch files or directories for filesystem activiy. From the manual the following events can be detected:

```
IN_ACCESS         File was accessed (read) (*).
IN_ATTRIB         Metadata changed, e.g., permissions, timestamps, extended attributes, link count (since Linux 2.6.25), UID, GID, etc. (*).
IN_CLOSE_WRITE    File opened for writing was closed (*).
IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE  File not opened for writing was closed (*).
IN_CREATE         File/directory created in watched directory (*).
IN_DELETE         File/directory deleted from watched directory (*).
IN_DELETE_SELF    Watched file/directory was itself deleted.
IN_MODIFY         File was modified (*).
IN_MOVE_SELF      Watched file/directory was itself moved.
IN_MOVED_FROM     File moved out of watched directory (*).
IN_MOVED_TO       File moved into watched directory (*).
IN_OPEN           File was opened (*).
```

From here you can google yourself a solution, but I think you get the overall idea. Of course this may only work on Linux, but from your question I assume you are using it (references to `rm` and `touch`).