# File.deleteOnExit - Unix trick from comments

Tags: android

Here's source comment for this method:

> Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination,
>        so calling this method will not ensure that files are deleted. Instead, you should
>        use the most appropriate out of:

```
 * Use a {@code finally} clause to manually invoke {@link #delete}.
 * Maintain your own set of files to delete, and process it at an appropriate point
    in your application's lifecycle.
 * Use the Unix trick of deleting the file as soon as all readers and writers have
   opened it. No new readers/writers will be able to access the file, but all existing
   ones will still have access until the last one closes the file.
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the "Unix trick" mentioned in it and how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer has a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5219960/200508. Basically, it means that "deleting" a file on a Unix system doesn't immediately erase it from disk; instead, it just deletes the reference to that file from the directory it's in. The file isn't actually erased until all processes which are using it terminate. Thus, you can open a temporary file and immediately delete it, and then whenever the program terminates it will be automatically erased.

Comment: I understand that. Just don't know the way to use this feature since I haven't ever worked with Unix systems.